# My new car is a lot more (too much) hot inside than my previous car, why and what can I do about it?

Tags: temperature

I had a Citroen C3 and I now have a Peugeot 207. For a reason I cannot understand, the 207 is A LOT more hot inside than the C3. I haven't measured it but the difference is probably 3 or 4 degrees celcius.

What is the likely cause and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Your heater or a/c setting.

Comment: I'm talking about when I enter my car in the morning, so I assume it's not related to these.

Comment: How is the inside compared to ambient temps? Does the car sit under shelter (garage or car port) or does it sit in the open? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Does it have more glass area?

Comment: @drake035 If you had mentioned that it was a "first thing in the morning" issue in your question then that would have helped us focus our answers.

Comment: Slightly more glass area but not enough for explaining the temperature difference I'm pretty sure. I'm in the UK, it's hotter than ambient temperature, car sits in the open just like previous car

Answer (score 1):

In a sunny climate, the color of the vehicle can contribute to the temperature one feels inside.

Another aspect of temperature is airflow. If your cabin climate controls are set to recirculate the air, it would close off any openings to the outside that might otherwise allow warmer air to exit and cooler air to enter.

The photo below comes from an eBay auction post:

[image: climate control panel]

The top center section, left side has the recirculation logo. It should be set to off to open the outside access door(s) and allow static air to flow.

Comment: Actually, if it's really hot outside, it may be better to recirculate the air after A/C has made the interior of the car cool enough. That saves some fuel.

Comment: A comment posted after the question indicates that this is while the car has been sitting idle overnight. For operation, your suggestion is certainly valid.

Comment: Thanks but I'm in the UK (not sunny) and recirculation was already off